# Veeam Backup & Replication for Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, hyper-v

I have 5 Hyper-V on each of them. I have created virtual machines with Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10. I want to get backup from these machines with Veeam Backup & Replication.

If I want to get backup from them I must turn off the virtual machines which I don't want to do, so I can't get a backup. Does anyone have any solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

During hyper-v backup, The backup data is processed using VSS snapshot of windows and we don't have to restart the machine. we used to write scripts and backup the data in our data center where restart is not need. I am sure that this requirement is specific to the software you are using. Also Veeam is good at backing up VMware servers and not hyper-v where they started support for the above recently. Where you can use some other software like Vembu,acronis for hyper-v backup.